# Ubuntu 12.04 - [drm] nouveau unknown i2c port, i can not use the PCI express card with VGA and HDMI output

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, drivers, nvidia, x11

I have this brand new PCI-Express cards (bought 10 of them geforce-gt-620).

[image]

where i am using 12.04 64-bit, and trying to use VGA + Hdmi outputs from that card. But Ubuntu is throwing this nonstop.

```
[32323233] [drm] nouveau [0000:01:00.0]: unknown i2c port 48
[32323233] [drm] nouveau [0000:01:00.0]: unknown i2c port 57
[32323233] [drm] nouveau [0000:01:00.0]: unknown i2c port 48
[32323233] [drm] nouveau [0000:01:00.0]: unknown i2c port 57
```

But i tried 12.10 same card seems to work there. How can i make the same card work under 12.04? (because on 12.10 i have some serious dependencies problem, can not use 12.10 as of this moment for those cards)

I have tried:

```
$ download kernel latest install it
$ download http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/
$ sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb

$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic              3.2.0-29.46                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic              3.2.0-35.55                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.1-030501-generic          3.5.1-030501.201208091310               Linux kernel image for version 3.5.1 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.6.0-030600rc3-generic       3.6.0-030600rc3.201208221735            Linux kernel image for version 3.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.1-030501-generic    3.5.1-030501.201208091310               Linux kernel image for version 3.5.1 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.6.0-030600rc3-generic 3.6.0-030600rc3.201208221735            Linux kernel image for version 3.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                       3.2.0.35.40                             Generic Linux kernel image
$ apt-get purge linux-image-3.6.0-030600rc3-generic  # did not solve the problem
$ update-grub2
$ init 6
$ uname -a
Linux sun-Alienware-X51 3.5.1-030501-generic #201208091310 SMP Thu Aug 9 17:11:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
$ sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

After reboot i can see HDMI output i have display but the VGA is not showing anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
```

Step 2:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current # just remove it do not install anything`

Step 3:

```
update the kernel

$ download http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-image-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.1-030501-generic_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_amd64.deb
wget http://91.189.94.216/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.1-030501_3.5.1-030501.201208091310_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
$ init 6
```

It works now!

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1280x720+0+48 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1280x720       60.0*+   50.0  
   1920x1080      50.0     60.0     25.0     30.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1680x945       60.0  
   1400x1050      74.9     59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     60.0  
   1440x576       25.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480       30.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   848x480        60.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0     59.9  
VGA-2 connected 1024x768+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1680x1050      74.9     60.0  
   1680x945       60.0  
   1400x1050      74.9     60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1366x768       60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0* 
   1024x576       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0
```